# $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=a+b+c+d=0$, show that the sum of a pair taken from $a,b,c,d$ is zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> It is known that $\{a,b,c,d\} \subset \Bbb R$ and
>   $$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=a+b+c+d=0$$.
>   Prove that a sum of a pair taken from $a,b,c,d$ is equal to zero.

This is from the "International Tournament of Cities - 94" a math competition held in Brazil. Tried with newton identities but no success. Any help will be appreciated. Sorry if it is a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for the problem statement. But this is how it was originally written. The "sum of a pair" means, I believe, the sum of  two distinct variables taken from the 4 original variables $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $d=-(a+b+c)$, substituting this into $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=0$ leads to $(a+b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3=0$, or $3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$. Thus one of the terms should be zero.

Edited: We have

$\begin{align*}
(a+b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3&=a^3+3a^2(b+c)+3a(b+c)^2+(b+c)^3-a^3-b^3-c^3\\
&=3a^2(b+c)+3a(b+c)^2+3bc(b+c)\\
&=3(b+c)(a^2+a(b+c)+bc)\\
&=3(b+c)(a+b)(a+c).
\end{align*}$

Comment: Very good answer! I’m curious: does “sum of a pair taken from $a,b,c,d$ is equal to zero” mean *each* of the $\binom42$ combinations must sum to $0$ or that *at least one* of the $\binom42$ combinations must sum to $0$? And could you briefly clarify how your answer adheres to that statement?

Comment: Please comment on how you conclude that $3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$. Isn't it true that $p_3=e_1^3-3e_1 e_2+3e_3$? ($p_3=a^3+b^3+c^3$, $e_1=(a+b+c)$ and $e_2=(ab+bc+ac), e_3=abc$. Then using the condition $p_3=e_1^3=0$, we get to $e_1 e_2=e_3$, how to get from this to $3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$. Possibly I'm getting something wrong.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor If one of the sums ($a+b, b+c, c+a$) is zero, it is clear that the residual sum (respectively $c+d, d+a, b+d$) is zero. And it is easy to see that if those two conditions holds then the cubic sum is zero. Since the problem said 'a sum of a pair' is zero, in your context it means at least one of the combinations sum to $0$, but anyway there are actually at least two combinations that sum to $0$ due to the condition.

Comment: @shrimpabcdefg Thank you; that clarifies a lot $\ddot\smile$

Comment: ... and you can see that not all pairs necessarily sum to zero as $(1,1,-1,-1)$ satisfies the conditions.