# Let a, b, c, d be complex numbers satisfying $a+b+c+d=a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=0$. Prove that a pair of the a, b, c, d must add up to 0

Tags: cubics, algebras

When doing this I tried using the identity
$x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$ if $x+y+z=0$

I take $x=a$, $y=b$, and $z=c+d$

So $a+b+(c+d)=0$

$a^3+b^3+(c+d)^3=3ab(c+d)$

$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+3cd(c+d)=3ab(c+d)$

$(a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)=3ab(c+d)-3cd(c+d)$

$0=3(c+d)(ab-cd)$

So I got $c+d=0$ or $ab=cd$

If $c+d=0$, the statement is true, but how about if it's $ab=cd$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3=a+b+c+d=0$, show that the sum of a pair taken from $a,b,c,d$ is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427837/a3b3c3d3-abcd-0-show-that-the-sum-of-a-pair-taken-from-a-b-c-d-is) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%3Da%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%2Bd%5E3%3D0%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Acomplex%2C%20OR%20content%3Apair%2C%20OR%20content%3Aadd&p=1).

Comment: If $ab=cd$ you try another pairing. If none of them works, it means that $ab=cd , ac=bd, ad=bc$ then see where that takes you.

Comment: Ah, John Omielan thank you for that!
Thank you too dxiv, ill try doing it

Comment: From $d=-a-b-c$, we have $ab-cd=ab-c(-a-b-c)=ab+ac+bc+c^2=a(b+c)+c(b+c)=(a+c)(b+c)$. This then matches the result in the proposed duplicate answer. Also, note the proposed duplicate only has the values being real, as opposed to complex, but that doesn't affect the result.

Comment: I see once again thank you @JohnOmielan